# Taking Last Element of the Tokenized String using StringTokenizer API

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

Im having a String Array as

```
 String[] input = {"$abs gf ,sd df,$ascd sr adf dfa -mcont 100, 434" , "$abs,sd,$ascd sr adf dfa -mcont 900, 43" };
```

Now I tried to tokenize and got four Tokens.The thrid token last value say **100 and 900** on the above example which is my required output. From the four tokens, how can i go through only to the 3rd token last element???

Kindly use StringTokenizer API,I dont want String split() functions to handle it.

Comment: The documentation for StringTokenizer itself says that the code must use String.split(). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: Also, your string array isn't a string array? I'm pretty confused on what you are splitting on and how.

Comment: @ Ankur String split() is supported on jdk1.5 onwards Im using 1.3 so only i said,For new code only recommended to split() function.

Comment: @ sanchit Yeah you are right , Im jus showing demo on my problem with string tokenizer from the array input.Jus Ignore the syntax error.Its not a big deal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
    st5 = new StringTokenizer(input[i],",");
    int tokCount = st5.countTokens();
    int tkcount = 0;

    while(st5.hasMoreElements()) {
        tkcount++;
        st5.nextToken();

        if((tokCount - 2) == tkcount){
            String str = st5.nextToken();

            if(str.indexOf("-mCont") == -1)
                break;

            String mcount = str.substring(str.indexOf("-mCont")+1);
            mcount = mcount.replace("mCont "," ");

            System.out.println(mcount);
       }
    }
}
```